# Setting Border for Table Header in iText7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am trying to build a table with a custom border width in itext7.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
public Table createBodyTable(Parameter parameter) throws XMLParserException {
        Table table = new Table(1);

    table.addHeaderCell(createHeader());

    table.addCell(createBody())
            .removeCellBorder()
            .setHeight(450F));

    table.addCell(createSum()
            .removeCellBorder());

    table.setBorder(new SolidBorder(1))
            .setPadding(0);

    return table;
}
```

**createHeader(); is a function call that returns an itext Table**

My result looks something like this

[image]

As visible, the border AROUND the table is set correctly, but border bottom for the header cell isn't the correct width.

If i use

```
table.addHeaderCell(createHeader().setBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(1)));
```

My result looks like this

[image]

As you can see, there are double borders.
As of now my solution to that problem is the following method

```
public Cell setTableBorderOnOneCell(int cellPosition, Border border){
        Cell cell = (Cell) this.getChildren().get(cellPosition);
        cell.setBorder(border);
        return cell;
    }
```

Which is a functional workaround but makes me think: Is there a correct way to do that?

Comment: Can you make sure that `createBodyTable` is compilable (include the definition of the methods this method depends upon and minimize)? Can you elaborate on why you think the "border bottom for the header cell isn't the correct width" and what should be the correct width in your opinion?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I'm not sure what you mean by "include the definition of methods this method depends upon and minimize". Could you elaborate? The function however is compilable, otherwise I wouldn't be able to get any results. 
The correct width in my eyes would be the one I set for the table: new SolidBorder(1); The result however shows a thinner border below the header cells.

Comment: How do I reproduce your problem? If I copy paste your code snippet and try to run it, I don't have the definition of `createHeader`, `createSum`, `createBody`. You need to attach the code that is runnable for everyone, and that is minimal.